# Solution for SAPUI5 error message because of templateShareable:true?

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Since an upgrade of SAPUI5 1.28.20 I receive the following error message:

> A shared template must be marked with templateShareable:true in the
>   binding info

Code is in MangedObject.js and looks like this:

```
        } else if ( oBindingInfo.templateShareable === MAYBE_SHAREABLE_OR_NOT ) {
            // a 'clone' operation implies sharing the template (if templateShareable is not set to false)
            oBindingInfo.templateShareable = oCloneBindingInfo.templateShareable = true;
            jQuery.sap.log.error("A shared template must be marked with templateShareable:true in the binding info");
        }
```

Value of `oBindingInfo.templateShareable` is `true`, value of `MAYBE_SHAREABLE_OR_NOT` is 1.

According to documentation the default of `oBindingInfo.templateShareable` is `true`.

So what is wrong here? A bug in the library? Or something with my code?
See also: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html

### Update for SAPUI5 version 1.32.x

With version 1.32.x the message has changed it is now:

> A template was reused in a binding, but was already marked as
>   candidate for destroy. You better should declare such a usage with
>   templateShareable:true in the binding configuration. -

but according to the documentation the default should still be true:

> {boolean} oBindingInfo.templateShareable?, Default: true  option to
>   enable that the template will be shared which means that it won't be
>   destroyed or cloned automatically

Now it looks like, that this produces some endless loading, I got this message again and again till the browser crashes.
Anyone an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer above marked as being correct is actually not correct at all because this here is wrong:**

> Looks like the message occurs if the template was instantiated outside
>   the binding. [...] This code seems to produce the message: [...]

To prove the answer above os wrong on your own just run this example (SAPUI5 1.28.20 has the same result):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>

        <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.12/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->
 
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
                
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                    Items: [
                        {Name: "Michael"},
                        {Name: "John"},
                        {Name: "Frank"},
                        {Name: "Jane"}
                    ]
                });                
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
                
                var oTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
                    text : "{Name}"
                });
              
                new sap.m.Select({
                    items : {
                        path : "/Items",
                        template : oTemplate
                    }
                }).placeAt("content");
            });
        </script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, a clear definition of the lifecycle for templates is (or was) missing in UI5. When this issue was detected there were already many older apps around... So now this new "feature" was introduced somewhen last year (which is kind of backwards compatible). UI5 tries to detect automatically the developer's intention about the lifecycle of a given template used in the binding (using some heuristic). If UI5 cannot clearly tell what the developer actually wanted then you will see this error log - which actually does not affect the functionality at all. It just tells the **developer** that there is a template somewhere which will not be destroyed by the UI5 runtime. In other words, **if you set templateShareable=true then you should make sure to destroy the template in order to avoid memory leaks**. So just setting **templateShareable=true** is not the whole story...

I have published a detailed blog about this: [Understanding templateShareable in SAPUI5](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/understanding-templateShareable-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the message occurs if the template was instantiated outside the binding. Example:

This code will work:

```
new sap.m.Select({
    items : {
        path : "/Items",
        template : new sap.ui.core.Item({
            text : "{Name}"
        }) 
    }
})
```

This code seems to produce the message:

```
var oTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
    text : "{Name}"
}) 


new sap.m.Select({
    items : {
        path : "/Items",
        template :oTemplate
    }
})
```

This seems to fix the problem:

```
var oTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
    text : "{Name}"
}) 


new sap.m.Select({
    items : {
        path : "/Items",
        template :oTemplate,
        templateShareable : true
    }
})
```

Comment: I was still running into the very same issue with the code below because a dropdown (Select) of my XML fragment was also lacking 'templateShareable' 

listView.bindItems({
    path: sDimAttrPath,
    template: sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.es.view.BoostItem"),
    templateShareable: true
});

XML fragment:
...
<Select selectedKey="=" forceSelection="false" width="100%" items="{path: 'uiTools>/operators', templateShareable: true}" >
...

Comment: I experienced the opposite problem. When entering an app for the second time from Fiori launchpad it gave me _Error: adding element with duplicate id ..._ for a template with an ID. Using `items="{..., templateShareable: false}"` solved the problem. (v1.26)